# IntegrityError at /admin/catalog/region/add/ (1062, "Duplicate entry..)

Tags: python, mysql, django

EDIT: see below - making a new database worked for me, but may not be an option for others!

[Django 1.6.8, MySQL)
Hi all.

I have a catalog model for a wine website. I'm getting an error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/catalog/region/add/

(1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'country_id'")
```

When I try to add a region to the admin page after adding a country. There's no views written yet to show. Just the admin page. The relevant part of the model is below. If you want the whole thing it's here: pastebin.com/RBpBcLmj

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Country E.g. Spain")
    writeup = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Blurb About the Country")
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Region(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Region E.g. Rioja")
    writeup = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Blurb About the Region")
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am a beginner, but I'm sure I've got the ForeignKey on the correct bit...? There are similar (unresolved) problems on SO. Any ideas what could cause this error?

- I have tried `python manage.py flush`. I re-enter the data - same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: OK. Haven't found a "real" solution - but making a brand new database w/different name worked. Looks like it was a MySQL thing - not a Django thing. Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: hm, maybe you initially have set `country` as some unique field provided syncdb or migrations; Later changed `country` to FK field and forgot to provide migration?